# How to use \psfrag with Simulink?

Tags: eps, matlab, psfrag

I have tried to draw a block diagram in Simulink that has annotation fields. Then I have exported it in eps format from Matlab command window:

```
print -deps -r300 -s resolver.eps
```

The picture looks like this:

[image]

I would like to change text in block diagram with greek letters, so I used \psfrag, but with no success. I have also opened the .eps file with editor and searched for text (U_sin, U_cos, theta, omega), but there are no such texts in the generated .eps file, so I thik \psfrag just can't replace anything. Does somebody have the solution?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \psfrag{U_sin}{$\U_{sin}$}
    \psfrag{U_cos}{$\U_{cos}$}
    \psfrag{omega}{$\hat{\omega}$}
    \psfrag{theta}{$\hat{\theta}$}
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{resolver2}
     \caption{\label{resolver1} Blokovna shema metode Angle Tracking Observer}
\end{figure}
```

EDIT:
I have imopted eps file into Inkscape and obviously there is the text information in the eps file as Inkscape recognize it, I have changed text into math form for LaTex and saved with option EPS + LaTex, using command \import in latex I got this.
[image]

Comment: I don't know simulink but if `-r300`  denotes writing a 300dp bitmap then it's a bitmap just wrapped in a postscript shell so it will not be amenable to editing. If all else fails just write it from simulink with no text at all and then overlay the latex text by coordinate

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried without -r300 option, but same result. I don't fully understand the eps file format, so I thought it is kind of usefull format, since LaTex has psfrag command. Thanks anyway for the tip, about to insert overlay text.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič can we see that EPS generated by simulink? Just to see what exactly it is that is being generated. Psfrag need some very particular conditions in order to work. Also remember `\cos` and `\sin`

Comment: @daleif I don't see the possibility to attach file in this forum, if that is what you are asing for. The file is 56kB.

Comment: you have to upload it to a file sharing site (here har loads and loads of these) and then post the link

Comment: @daleif http://www.filedropper.com/resolver2 , that wasn't so difficult.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič it is a rather strange eps. Clearly not suited for psfrag. The fonts are handled "interestingly" and you are correct the strings `psfrag` could have searched for are nowhere to be found. Might even be easier to just redo the image in tikz. The base drawing for this image is very easy to make, and would problably end up looking better (are the arrows manually placed in this program? For example the arrow from the dot to K2 is off center in regards to the dot.

Comment: @daleif I wish I could learn tikz, to make but it seems very complicated to me.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič not really, here it is just a matter of placing some nodes (of various shapes), name them and lastly draw arrows. The placing can be determined by doing a sketch on squared paper first (to get an idea of the dimensions). Once you've learned it, you will not regret it

Comment: @daleif Is there any tutorial, to learn from beginning?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič see the manual, there is a test case at the beginning

Answer (score 3):

This is just a long comment about doing the drawing in tikz instead. Here are some starting points given without comments, most is explained in the tikz manual, plus there are loads and loads of tikz answers on this site:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,shapes.geometric}



\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  myBox/.style={
    draw,
    minimum height=6mm,
    minimum width=6mm,
  },
  myCircle/.style={
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum height=6mm,
    minimum width=6mm,
  },
  myTriangle/.style={
    draw,
    %isosceles triangle,
    regular polygon, 
    regular polygon sides=3,
    shape border rotate=-90,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum width=6mm,
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[myBox] (T1) at (0,0) {$X$};
  \node[myBox] (T2) at ($(T1)+(0,-3)$) {$X$};
  \node[myCircle] (T3) at ($(T1)!0.5!(T2)+(1,0)$) {$\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{+}{-}$};
  \node[myBox] (T4) at ($(T2)+(0,-1)$) {$\sin$};
  \node[myTriangle] (T5) at ($(T3)+(1.5,0)$) {$K_1$};

  \coordinate (T6) at ($(T3.east)!0.5!(T5.west)$);
  \fill (T6) circle (2pt);

  \begin{scope}[shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt]
    \draw[->] (T1) -| (T3);
    \draw[->] (T2) -| (T3);
    \draw[->] (T4.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- (T1.west);
    \draw[->] (T3) -- (T5);
    % start from the center of the dot
    \draw[shorten <=0pt,->] (T6) |- (T4);
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]